# Jquery simple script works only locally....why? Like Javascript translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, translation

I'm working on a small js script that allows me to change the subfolder of the site (to switch language). Basically it works only locally but not over the Internet ... the condition evaluates always true ... can you help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var trUrlRu = window.location.href.replace(/\/ru\//, '/');
    var trUrlIt = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/ru" + window.location.pathname;


    if(window.location.href.indexOf("ru") > -1)
     { $('.lang a').addClass('it').attr('href',trUrlRu);}
       else
     { $('.lang a').addClass('ru').attr('href',trUrlIt);};  

});
```

`trUrlRu` removes the "/ ru /" and replaces with "/"

and

`trUrlRu` adds "/ ru" after the domain name, eg `http://blabla.org/ru`

Let's see if you understand better, I created two functions:

1. delete "/ ru" from link
2. add "/ ru" to the link

Then check with if the url contains the string "/ ru" and:

1. present: remove "/ ru"
2. is not present: add "/ ru"

Comment: So the problem is that `window.location.href.indexOf("ru")` always returns something > -1 ?

Comment: Yes if online it's return every time True...

Comment: I have to ask this - what is the URL?  And should you not be looking for `"/ru/"`?

Comment: But if i run the script standalone like: if(window.location.href.indexOf("ru") > -1) {alert('Ru present');} else  {alert('No Ru detected');};

Comment: I would check if ru is present in the link if present delete the /ru string in the url else add /ru to the current url after domain.com

Comment: Solved by adding an "/" slash like this window.location.href.indexOf("/ru") > -1)

Comment: So what you're saying is, when you uploaded it the domain name had the letters "ru" in it?

Comment: now i have two link:  **example.it/index.html** and  **example.it/ru/index.html**... i hope it will help someone ^^

Answer (score -1):

It is easy, actually: http://jsfiddle.net/WR6vr/ :)
All you need is use `match` and `replace` methods. `location.href` can be updated after you have made changes :)

Comment: I hope it will help you out!

Comment: But i have these structures: 1) http://site.com/blog/ and 2) http://site.com/ru/blog and not http://site.com/it/blog

Comment: Solved with adding an "/" to if condition .... strange...why? but works ^^ 

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

     var trUrlRu = window.location.href.replace(/\/ru\//, '/');
     var trUrlIt = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/ru" + window.location.pathname;
     
     if(window.location.href.indexOf("/ru") >= 0)
         { $('.lang a').addClass('it').attr('href', trUrlRu);}
        else
      { $('.lang a').addClass('ru').attr('href', trUrlIt);};
        
    });